# Similar function to GetLastError in objective-C/C?

Tags: c, objective-c, sockets, setsockopt, getlasterror

I'm doing some lovely socket programming in objective-C right now and part of my code is giving me an error (in the setsockopt method call). I was wondering if anyone knows of a similar function to the GetLastError() function in C++ that I could use in objective-C to determine the problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the value of [`errno`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html) if the `setsockopt` returns a negative value.

From [`setsockopt` manpage](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/setsockopt.html):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion,
>   setsockopt() returns 0. Otherwise, -1
>   is returned and errno is set to
>   indicate the error.

You can see some standard `errno` values [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html#tag_02_03).